SteamVR, Ubuntu 24.04 LTS, & Gnome Wayland
Having recently gotten Steam installed on my new Ubuntu PC, I am now trying to troubleshoot some problems with SteamVR on Ubuntu.
A SteamVR support article says that "Gnome Wayland, the default desktop environment for Ubuntu, is not supported as it does not support DRM leasing.  Users using Gnome Wayland will need to switch to an alternative window manager/compositor in order to use SteamVR."
Source: https://help.steampowered.com/en/faqs/view/18A4-1E10-8A94-3DDA
So I guess I'm just wondering if these directions from Steam apply to my particular situation here.  Because they also say in the same article:  "Some compatible window managers/compositors include [...] All X11 Window Managers and Compositors".
So I'm a bit confused here if I need to change my desktop environment, based on this article, or if it doesn't apply to me... because my system specs appear to say I'm using the X11 Windowing System, and Steam says that is compatible.  But it also says the default Ubuntu desktop environment (which I think I am using...) is problematic.  Maybe the article was written for those using older versions of Ubuntu from before 24.04 LTS? I don't notice a date on the article.
I'm confused about if these directions apply to me or not having installed the standard Ubuntu 24.04 LTS.
I'm not sure if it matters for the sake of this question but I think the version of Steam I installed is either the one from "sudo apt install steam-installer" or maybe it was "sudo apt install steam" ... installed via the terminal.  So I guess presumably that would be the .deb rather than the Snap or the flatpak(?), if that matters.
System specs:
OS: Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
Processor: AMD Ryzen 5 5600X
RAM: 32GB
SSD: 1TB
Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3070
OS type: 64 bit
Gnome version: 46
Windowing system: X11
Kernel version: Linux 6.8.0-41-generic
VR Hardware: Valve Index

As the page states, X11 compositors are supported, including Ubuntu's default GNOME. In the upcoming 47 version (24.10), it will be supported in both Wayland and X11.

I recently had the displeasure of trying to make my Quest 3 work on Linux. And as far as I know - there's really no way to make it consistently work on Wayland sadly.
However, after I switched to Mint 23, I was able to semi-easly make VR work. I used apt version of Steam and installed ALVR:

Install Steam via apt (Flatpak version does not work, as SteamVR needs elevated privileges to configure itself)
Install SteamVR from your library
Go to ALVR Github, and from Releases download alvr_streamer_linux.tar.gz
Extract the archive, and run ./alvr_streamer_linux/bin/alvr_dashboard
Follow the steps given during installation

If you done everything correctly, this should now work, provided you have Steam running. You can create .desktop entry for alvr_dashboard, as you have to launch SteamVR from ALVR Dashboard.
However - I have an AMD GPU. No idea if this will work on NVidia, you will have to check.
